# Do these for loops enumerate all the contents of the array by default?

Tags: ruby, arrays, for-loop

I'm trying to figure out whether I should avoid looping through arrays this way if I only want its specific sections.

```
the_count = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]     
fruits = ["apples", "oranges", "pears", "apricots"]

for number in the_count
  puts "This is count #{number}"
end

fruits.each do |fruit|
  puts "A fruit of type: #{fruit}"
end
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not understanding the question.  Can you tell us what output you're looking for?

Comment: My question is does the first for loop go through all of 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 of the_count, and second do routine to enumerate all of "apples", "oranges", "pears", and "apricots" of fruits.

Comment: OK, I've answered (the answer is "yes") but I still don't really understand.  What else would the loops do other than go through all of the elements?

Comment: That's a good question. I came from a background of programming in C and C++. So this two specific semantics are quite new to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of the loops you describe will indeed go through all of the elements in the array.  What else would they do?  If you just want a single item from an array, use `fruits[2]`, or if you want just part of the array, use `fruits.slice(1,3)` or `fruits.slice(1..3)` (the first one returns 3 elements starting from element 1 (i.e. the second one), the second returns elements 1 through 3).